# schedule to update database based on the change of another db

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am building a application that has both server side and client side.

The server side is a ui interface that can modify the server database, and the server provide an endpoint to return json object for GET requests.

The client side has a database may or may not share the same schema with server db. I have a cron job to call a java application to get and parse the json object with the GET request.

My question is that whether there is any way to let the client side db to only update the changed data from the server db since the last get request called by this client. (there may be other client using the GET request)

specifically,

1. is it possible to let the client notify the server side which data it wants and let the server side only returns changed data in json object?
2. is it possible to let the server side to contain everything in the json object and let client side picks the updated data.

The application is mainly coded in java with mysql.

The index(id) of each table for the server side db is stable, which means there may be insert, delete, and update, but the id of a row is never updated.

Comment: 1. Oracle had triggers , maybe some equivalent in mysql .
2. multicast update request to persist in multiple databases .
3. (worst idea : resource instensive) periodic delayed method to check for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up create an extra "last_updated" column in my server db and use that column to identify whether the row is changed after some time point.

I know this is a bit skewed from my original question. Yet it is a straightforward and easy way to achieve what I wanted.